# UISearchDisplayController does not update search results

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have the following search setup in my app:

```
- (UISearchBar*)searchBar
{

    if (!_searchBar) {

        _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
        _searchBar.delegate = self;
        _searchBar.placeholder = kSearchBarPlaceHolder;
    }
    return _searchBar;
}
- (UISearchDisplayController*)searchBarDisplayContr
{

    if (!_searchBarDisplayContr) {

        _searchBarDisplayContr = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
        _searchBarDisplayContr.delegate = self;
        _searchBarDisplayContr.searchResultsDataSource = self.tableView.dataSource;
        _searchBarDisplayContr.searchResultsDelegate = self.tableView.delegate;
        _searchBarDisplayContr.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _searchBarDisplayContr.searchResultsTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    }

    return _searchBarDisplayContr;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)searchResults
{

    if (!_searchResults) {
        _searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:_restaurants.count];
    }

    return _searchResults;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    [self.restaurants enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Restaurant *restaurant, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [restaurant.name isEqualToString:scope]) {

            NSRange range = [restaurant.name rangeOfString:searchText
                                                   options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];


            if (range.length > 0) {
                [self.searchResults addObject:restaurant];
            }
       }

    }];



}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController*)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString*)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:@"All"];



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        for (UIView *v in controller.searchResultsTableView.subviews) {
            if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                ((UILabel *)v).text = kSearchResultsTableViewNoResultsLabel;
                ((UILabel *)v).font = [UIFont mediumFontOfSize:20.0f];
                ((UILabel *)v).textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                break;
            }
        }
    });


    return YES;
}



- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController*)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchBarDisplayContr.searchBar text]
                               scope:@"All"];

    return YES;
}
```

But for some reason when I search the searchResultsTableView is not updated / cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called. The tableView delegates and DataSource is setup in my storyboard.

Any ideas why this is happening?

UPDATE:

```
 [self.tableView registerClass:[RestaurantsCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    [self.searchBarDisplayContr.searchResultsTableView registerClass:[RestaurantsCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchBarDisplayContr.searchResultsTableView) {

        return [self.searchResults count];

    } else {       

           return [self.restaurants count];


    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    RestaurantsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    Restaurant *restaurant;

    if (tableView == self.searchBarDisplayContr.searchResultsTableView) {

        if (self.searchResults.count > 0) {

            restaurant = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];


        }


    } else {   

 if (self.restaurants.count > 0) {     

          restaurant = self.restaurants[indexPath.row];

}

    }


    if (restaurant) {

        cell.titleLabel.text = restaurant.name;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you have another table view in your controller? Can you show us your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfSection` and `numberOfRows` methods?

Comment: Updated with the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the offending line:

```
RestaurantsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Should be:

```
RestaurantsCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

**Explanation:**

If the tableView turns out to be your search results table view, then trying to dequeue a cell with an identifier won't work because it doesn't have prototype cells. Therefore, you have to use `self.tableView`

Also, your code can be cleaned up a lot:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return (tableView == self.tableView) ? self.restaurants.count : self.searchResults.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    RestaurantsCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    Restaurant *restaurant = (tableView == self.tableView) ? self.restaurants[indexPath.row] ? self.searchResults[indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = restaurant.name;
    return cell;
}
```

**Edit**
Check out [this example](https://github.com/MichaelSnowden/RandomAnswer)

Comment: Thank you, but that does not seem to change anything :/

Comment: I have registered a TableViewCell class for the prototypecells with a resueidentifier (the one in my storyboard) in my ViewDidLoad, does this make a difference?

Comment: @Seya I'd have to see more of your code. I'm going to make an example search table view class for you in a moment. Take a look at it when I post it in about 5 minutes.